# Turn on 2 leds with a toggle switch

Tags: gpio

I have a toggle button with 3 pins. I want to use it to turn 2 leds, when it's in one position turn on one led (red) and when it's in the other position turn on the other led (green).

I found a lot of information about push buttons, but no about toggle buttons. I tried it using the 5V GPIO like in the schematic below.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDbZsW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now I want to use 2 GPIOs as inputs to know what led is receiving the current. I'm sure it's possible, i'm sure it's easy but i'm a noob.

My idea is do this:

```
GPIO.setup(20, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(21, GPIO.IN)

green_led_state = GPIO.input(20)
red_led_state = GPIO.input(21)
if green_led_state == True and red_led_state == False:
    print('Green led active')
if red_led_state == True and green_led_state == True:
    print('Red led active')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must **not** connect a Pi GPIO to a voltage outside the range 0 to 3.3V.  If you do so you will eventually destroy the GPIO and then the Pi.

Assuming you are using 3.3V.

Connect a GPIO to the green LED at the switch.

If the GPIO is high the green LED is on, otherwise the red LED is on.

Comment: Thank you very much, you think I need to put some resistors?

Comment: Yes, you need a resistor in series with each LED.  Something like 330 ohms should be fine.  If you search on-line you will probably find info about resistors for each colour of LED if you want to match apparent brightness.

Answer (score 1):

You can connect any LED that has a forward voltage of > 3 volts directly with a GPIO pin of a Raspberry.

To calculate the resistor:

Normally 10 mA is reasonably bright for a LED. However, if you want the maximum, check the Raspberry documentation for the recommended maximum current per output pin.

The steps are:

- Find the forward voltage of the LED (Vf), let's say 2 V.
- Calculate the resistor: V = I * R <=> ( 3 - Vf) = 0.01 * R <=> R = (3 - 1) / 0.01 = R <=> R = 100 ohm

For the other LED, you perform the same steps (probably the red and green LED have different forward voltages). Also it is high likely that 10 mA for a LED red looks more or less bright than 10 mA for a green LED.

---

About the program:

It is common not to write `== True` or `== False` in boolean expressions, you can leave the `== True` away, and instead of `== False` you can write `not` in front of the expression, thus:

```
if green_led_state and not red_led_state:
    print('Green led active')
if red_led_state and green_led_state:
    print('Red led active')
```

The last condition from your program is strange: you check for both LEDs to be green and write `Red led active`. I think you probably mean:

```
if green_led_state and not red_led_state:
    print('Green led active')
if not red_led_state and green_led_state:
    print('Red led active')
```

Answer (score 0):

try the code below(untested)

```
import time 
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM) 

G = 17
R = 27

GPIO.setup(G, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(R, GPIO.IN)

i=1
while (i<10):
    if(GPIO.input(r)==HIGH):
        print ('RED led is active')
    if(GPIO.input(g)==HIGH):
        print ('RED led is active')
```